# Sword Block for PVP

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When clicking right click on your computer mouse while holding a sword, the sword blocks. I heard that it helps PVP. Does it really help? When someone hits you with a sword while you block, does it do less damage to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you block with your sword by right clicking, it halves any damage dealt to you. This includes melee attacks, arrows and explosions. However, it does not reduce fall damage.

Blocking does not decrease the durability of a sword. Players move slower than sneaking when blocking.

Comment: @Anonymous If it helped, please click the green tick below the votes. Thankyou!

Comment: I can't find the green tick

Comment: @Anonymous It should be grey. It will turn green once you click it.

Comment: Is it the up button? I can't find it on my phone, i'll try to look later on the computer.